# Tkinter Canvas Image Not Displaying Even with Reference saved

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

So I have this code:

```
def addTux(self, h,w,g):
    global root
    cx = h/(2*g)
    cy = w/(2*g)

    img = Image.open("sprites/tux.png")

    img.thumbnail((g,g))
    print "The size of the Image is: "
    print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)
    # img.show()
    self.p_sprite = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    root.p_sprite = self.p_sprite
    self.tux = self.canvas.create_image(cx*g, cy*g, image=self.p_sprite)

    c = self.canvas.coords(self.tux)
    print c
```

`print c` prints coords...
`img.show()` opens my penguiny thumbnail (when it's not commented out)...
but Tkinter doesn't show squat.

`self.canvas.pack()` is called later, and I'm saving two references to the PhotoImage just to be double sure it's not garbage collected.

All I get is a white screen.

I'm sure it's a short in the wetware... just not sure where. Any ideas?

All Code below:

app.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import constants

class Application(Frame):
    def addTux(self, h,w,g):
        global root
        cx = h/(2*g)
        cy = w/(2*g)

        img = Image.open("sprites/tux.png")
        root.img = img

        img.thumbnail((g,g))
        print "The size of the Image is: "
        print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)
        img.show()
        self.p_sprite = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        root.p_sprite = self.p_sprite
        self.tux = self.canvas.create_image(cx*g, cy*g, image=self.p_sprite)
        self.canvas.pack()

        c = self.canvas.coords(self.tux)
        print c

    def createTiles(self):
        h = constants.bounds["y"][1]
        w = constants.bounds["x"][1]
        g = constants.grid_size

        self.grid = []
        # for i in range(0,(h/g)):
        #     # self.grid.append([])
        #     # print self.grid[i]
        #     for j in range(0,(w/g)):
        #         s = self.canvas.create_rectangle(j * g, i*g, (j+1)*g, (i+1)*g, fill="green")
        #         # self.grid[i].append(s)
        self.addTux(h,w,g)
        self.canvas.pack()

    def createWidgets(self):
        global root
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.frame, height=constants.bounds["y"][1]+10, width=constants.bounds["x"][1]+10, background="red")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.createTiles()
        print self.p_sprite

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

constants.py:

```
grid_size=40

bounds = {
    "x": [0,1000],
    "y": [0,720]
}
```

Comment: If you set the canvas background, does the screen colour change?  It may be an issue of your Canvas not being placed properly

Comment: I can place other things on the canvas so I don't think that's it, but I'll try. (eg. I had a grid on it before and I went to place my sprite on the grid... thought it might be behind, so removed grid, and still nothing)

Comment: `background="red"` worked as expected.

Comment: I think your issue may be that the syntax is not `ImageTk.PhotoImage` but rather `Tk.PhotoImage`.  Try changing that and see if it works.

Comment: `class Tk has no attribute 'PhotoImage'`

Comment: tried the `PhotoImage` from Tkinter library but it ate itself on the image. This code at least doesn't throw any errors.

Comment: Ahh sorry about that, just realized from your syntax you're using 2.7, not 3.x.  I'll keep looking at it and see if I can come up wit ha solution for ya

Comment: What is `constants.grid_size`? If that's a large number then your image will be drawn out of the viewable area.

Comment: Novel, it's 40.

Comment: Please add the contents of the `constants.py` module to your question otherwise it not "All Code".

Comment: what is the size of `tux.png`? Have you verified that the coordinates being computed in `addTux` are what you think they should be? You aren't specifying the `anchor` option, which means the image is centered on the coordinates. Are you certain that will result in a visible image?

Comment: it's the fact that tux.png is a png. I just converted it to gif and it worked.

Comment: Your code works for me on Windows 7, Python 2.7.13 (using my own small `.png` (38 x 40 pixels) image.

Comment: https://pixabay.com/en/penguin-tux-neanderthal-tarzan-161418/ is the picture I was using. I'm on a Mac OSX 10.11.6, Python 2.7.10

Comment: It works for me in python 3.6 (after changing `Tkinter` to `tkinter`, and `print` to `print()`; using a large JPEG, it shows a small BMP on canvas, and opens it in a separate temporary file as well.

Comment: Is it maybe just that png? I dunno, I ran it through an online converter, made a gif, and now it's working.